Java Standard HttpClient performance
I have a loop of 100 iterations which makes async requests to the same web server. The web server is dummy one - it returnes the response after 3 seconds delay.
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(uri)
            .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString("Hello"))
            .build();

    CompletableFuture<?> result = httpClient.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
            .thenAccept(r -> {
                System.out.printf(
                        "[%s] Thread: %s, Status: %s, Body: %s%n",
                        Instant.now(), Thread.currentThread().getName(), r.statusCode(), r.body()
                );
            });
}

The code above runs approx. 19 seconds.
Changing the parallelism setting in the range 2-11 (11 is default on my machine) have almost no effect.
But if I create another client with the same default ForkJoinPool and send requests with alternation:
HttpClient httpClient1 = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
HttpClient httpClient2 = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(uri)
            .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString("Hello"))
            .build();

    HttpClient httpClient = i % 2 == 0 ? httpClient1 : httpClient2;

    CompletableFuture<?> result = httpClient.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
            .thenAccept(r -> {
                System.out.printf(
                        "[%s] Thread: %s, Status: %s, Body: %s%n",
                        Instant.now(), Thread.currentThread().getName(), r.statusCode(), r.body()
                );
            });
}

the code takes only 12 seconds to run.
From logs I see that both clients use the same threads to execute.
What limit am I reaching in the first scenario? Is it connections per route? Is it tunable somehow (via JVM agrs or somehow else)?

Apparently it was a short-term anomaly. I was not able to reproduce this behavior once again.
The reason for the low performance was in my target Web-server - Wiremock. When using responses with delay, the Wiremock's worker thread blockes.
In order to provide high throughput, you need to setup Wiremock appropriately:

either increase the number of worker threads: options().containerThreads(110)
or enable asynchronous response processing mode: options().asynchronousResponseEnabled(true)

After setting this up, 100 requests were processed in about 4 seconds.
